# Comparison setting only one flag

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to avoid register flag dependency in my loop and I consider is there any compare instruction for integer which set just CF or OF flag.
And only that flags. The important fact is: Is one operand greater or not so the one bit is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.  What exactly are you trying to avoid?  All CPUs (except P4) rename different parts of EFLAGS separately, so [`inc` doesn't have a false dependency on the old value of EFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36510865/224132).  Usually when you want to loop without modifying a flag, it's `CF` that you're trying to preserve.  (For an `adc` loop, or shifting bits out of a register into `CF` one at a time.)

You can loop without affecting flags at all with `lea` and `jrcxz`, but that's not worth it for an `adc` loop on Intel SnB and later, where partial-flag merging is fast.

---

But if you need an actual compare, not just a count-down ([like the slow `loop` instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)), you could do it like this:

```
### Don't actually do this.  This is just to illustrate how bad the best option is
# A in eax,  B in ebx
movd      xmm0, eax
movd      xmm1, ebx
pcmpgtqd  xmm0, xmm1    ; all-ones if eax>ebx (32bit signed compare), else all-0
movd      ecx
jrcxz   A_ngt_B
;  fall-through path: A > B,  ecx = -1
```

This sucks a lot, compared to other options.  It's probably worse than simply saving/restoring flags with `sahf`/`lahf`, or the even-slower `pushf/popf`.  Often you can "save" a flag with a `setcc dl` or something, and then some kind of `test` or `sub dl, 1` to generate a carry or not.

To accomplish exactly what the question asked for (conditionally setting just `CF` without affecting others), use that branch on `jrcxz` to conditionally run `stc` or `clc` to set or clear `CF`.

---

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.