# What is the correct way to loop if I use ECX in loop (Assembly)

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

I am currently learning assembly language, and I have a program which outputs "Hello World!" :

```
        section .text                                                                                    
        global _start                                                                                    
_start:                                                                                                                                                                                               
        mov ebx, 1                                                                                       
        mov ecx, string                                                                                  
        mov edx, string_len                                                                              
        mov eax, 4                                                                                      
        int 0x80                                                                                                                                                                          
        mov eax, 1                                                                                       
        int 0x80                                                                                         

        section .data                                                                                    
        string db "Hello World!", 10, 0                                                                  
        string_len equ $ - string
```

I understand how this code works. But, now, I want to display 10 times the line. The code which I saw on the internet to loop is the following:

```
 mov ecx, 5
 start_loop:
 ; the code here would be executed 5 times
 loop start_loop
```

Problem : I tried to implement the loop on my code but it outputs an infinite loop. I also noticed that the loop needs `ECX` and the write function also needs `ECX`. What is the correct way to display 10 times my "Hello World!" ?

This is my current code (which produces infinite loop):

```
        section .text                                                                                    
        global _start                                                                                    
_start:                                                                                                  
        mov ecx, 10                                                                                      
myloop:                                                                                                  
        mov ebx, 1 ;file descriptor                                                                                      
        mov ecx, string                                                                                 
        mov edx, string_len                                                                             
        mov eax, 4   ; write func                                                                                    
        int 0x80                                                                                         
        loop myloop                                                                                      
        mov eax, 1   ;exit                                                                                    
        int 0x80                                                                                         

        section .data                                                                                    
        string db "Hello World!", 10, 0                                                                  
        string_len equ $ - string
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`loop` uses the `ecx` register. This is easy the remember because the `c` stands for `counter`.  You however overwrite the `ecx` register so that will never work!

The easiest fix is to **use a different register for your loop counter**, and avoid the `loop` instruction.

```
    mov   edi,10                      ;registers are general purpose
loop:
    ..... do loop stuff as above
    ;push edi                         ;no need save the register
    int   0x80
    ....                              ;unless you yourself are changing edi
    int   0x80
    ;pop  edi                         ;restore the register. Remember to always match push/pop pairs.                      
    sub   edi,1                       ;sub sometimes faster than dec and never slower
    jnz   loop
```

There is no right or wrong way to loop.
(Unless you're looking for every last cycle, which you are not, because you've got a system call inside the loop.)

The disadvantage of `loop` is that [it's slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently) than the equivalent `sub ecx,1` ; `jnz start_of_loop`.

The advantage of `loop` is that it uses less instruction bytes.  Think of it as a code-size optimization you can use *if* ECX happens to be a convenient register for looping, but at the cost of speed on some CPUs.

---

Note that the use of `dec reg` + `jcc label` [is discouraged for some CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter) (Silvermont / Goldmont being still relevant, Pentium 4 not). Because `dec` only alters part of the flags register it can require an extra merging uop.  Mainstream Intel and AMD rename parts of EFLAGS separately so there's no penalty for `dec` / `jnz` (because `jnz` only reads one of the flags written by `dec`), and can even micro-fuse into a dec-and-branch uop on Sandybridge-family.  (But so can `sub`).  `sub` is never worse, except code-size, so you may want to use `sub reg,1` for the forseeable future.

A system call using `int 80h` does not alter any registers other than `eax`, so as long as you remember not to mess with `edi` you don't need the push/pop pair.  Pick a register you don't use inside the loop, or you could just use a stack location as your loop counter directly instead of push/pop of a register.

Comment: Hello Johan, thank you very much for this perfect answer. I just have one question: Why is the loop working with edi ? (and not with ecx) ? Thank you very much

Comment: @void why should it work with `ecx`? `ecx` is already used by the sys_write, so unless you want to resolve the clash by storing/restoring the counter value ahead of every sys_write call, you just give up on `ecx` and use any other free register. BTW, don't use `loop` instruction (unless coding for 256 byte intro), use `dec ecx` `jnz start_loop` (sort of simulates "loop" instruction, and can be used with any register as counter). `loop` is artificially slow and fixed to `ecx`.