# Why use leal instead of incq?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, x86-64

I was fooling around and found that the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int& x){
    x+=1;
}

int main(){
    int a = 12;
    f(a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

when translated by `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4` with `g++ main.cpp -S` produces this assembly (showing only the relevant parts)

```
_Z1fRi:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %eax
    leal    1(%rax), %edx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edx, (%rax)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $12, -4(%rbp)
    leaq    -4(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _Z1fRi
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

**Question:** Why would the compiler choose to use `leal` instead of `incq`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Please look at the optimised code.  And update your post if there are differences.

Comment: How would it use `incq` in this case? `incq` is unary. And the compiler needs `rdx = rax + 1`. Maybe the real question is: why did it choose to involve two registers where one would be sufficient (with `incq`)? Is this optimized code? Apparently not.

Comment: `lea` is also useful in that it doesn't affect any flags register values, which is *very* useful to x86[-64] code, where so many instructions do. It's just a better paradigm. `inc` also introduced other issues like partial flags register stalls. The real question is *why* would you use `inc` instead of `lea` here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You compiled without optimization.  GCC does not make any effort to select particularly well-fitting instructions when building in "debug" mode; it just focuses on generating the code as quickly as possible (and with an eye to making debugging easier—*e.g.*, the ability to set breakpoints on source code lines).

When I enable optimizations by passing the `-O2` switch, I get:

```
_Z1fRi:
    addl    $1, (%rdi)
    ret
```

With generic tuning, the `addl` is preferred because [some Intel processors (specifically Pentium 4, but also possibly Knight's Landing) have a false flags dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter).

With `-march=k8`, `incl` is used instead.

There *is* sometimes [a use-case for `leal` in optimized code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction), though, and that is when you want to increment a register's value and store the result in a *different* register. Using `leal` in this way would allow you to preserve the register's original value, without needing an additional `movl` instruction. Another advantage of `leal` over `incl`/`addl` is that `leal` doesn't affect the flags, which can be useful in instruction scheduling.

Comment: Fun fact: `-O0` code is horrible on purpose because it wants to let you *modify* variables in memory with a debugger while stopped at any breakpoint, and still have the program execute as written.  This is why *everything* is always spilled to memory after a statement (or source line?), and reloaded after.  Debug-info formats unfortunately can't specify that a variable is currently live in a register.