# how do i rotate a value in assembly

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86-64

I am implementing a function in assembly x86 64 bits, which I am unable to alter:

```
   unsigned long rotate(unsigned long val, unsigned long num, unsigned long direction);
```

direction- 1 is left and 0 is right.

This is my code to shift left but its not working the last bit is off. Can someone help me please.

```
  rotate: 
  push rbp 
  push rdi
  push rsi
  push rdx
  mov rbp, rsp 
  sub rsp, 16
  cmp rdx, 1
  je shift_left


shift_left: 
   mov rax, rdi
   shl rax, cl
   mov rax, rax
   mov rcx, rdi
   sub cl, 64
   shl rcx, cl 
   or rax rdx
   mov rax, rax
   add rsp, 16
   #I pop all the registers used and ret
```

Comment: Please show your inputs, what result you expect, and what you get. Be sure to test with several different inputs to see the patterns in the errors.

Comment: Which ABI are you using? I mean, which registers are your parameters in?

Comment: Is `unsigned long` the same as `uint64_t` on your platform? What behavior do you expect if the shift count `num` exceeds operand width of `val`? Is the interface fixed, or can it be modified? In particular, why separate direction and shift count? For example, Fortran uses the convention that a negative shift count means "shift right", while positive shift count means "shift left". This lends itself to efficient implementation.

Answer (score 4):

x86 has rotate instructions.  Use [`rol rax, cl`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/RCL:RCR:ROL:ROR.html) to rotate left, and `ror rax, cl` to rotate right.

It seems you didn't realize that `cl` is the low byte of `rcx` / `ecx`.  Thus **`shl rcx, cl` is shifting the shift-count**.  Your function is over-complicated, but that's normal when you're just learning.  It takes practice to find the simple underlying problem that you can implement in few instructions.

Also, I think `mov rcx, rdi` was supposed to be `mov rcx, rsi`.  IDK what `mov rax,rax` was supposed to be; its just a no-op.

---

It would be significantly more efficient to call different functions for rotate-left vs. rotate-right, unless you actually need `direction` to be a runtime variable that isn't just a build-time constant 1 or 0.

Or to make it branchless, conditionally do `cl = 64-cl`, because a left-rotate by `n` is the same thing as a right-rotate by `64-n`.  And because rotate instructions mask the count (and rotate is modular anyway), you can actually just do `-n` instead of `64-n`.  (See [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c) for some C that uses `-n` instead of `32-n`, and compiles to a single rotate instruction).

TL:DR Because of rotate symmetry, you can rotate in the other direction just by negating the count.  As [@njuffa points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396960/how-do-i-rotate-a-value-in-assembly/47401051#comment81760123_47396960), **you could have written the function with a signed shift count** where negative means rotate the other way, so the caller would pass you `num` or `-num` in the first place.

Note that in your code, `sub cl, 64` has no effect on the shift count of the next `shl`, because 64-bit `shl` already masks the count with `cl & 63`.

---

I made a C version to see what compilers would do (on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Climits.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cx86intrin.h%3E++//+for+_lrotl,+but+clang+doesn!'t+seem+to+have+it%0A%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%0Astatic+inline+uint64_t+rotl64+(uint64_t+n,+unsigned+int+c)%0A%7B%0A++const+unsigned+int+mask+%3D+(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(n)+-+1)%3B++//+assumes+width+is+a+power+of+2.%0A%0A++//+assert+(+(c%3C%3Dmask)+%26%26%22rotate+by+type+width+or+more%22)%3B%0A++c+%26%3D+mask%3B%0A++return+(n%3C%3Cc)+%7C+(n%3E%3E(+(-c)%26mask+))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astatic+inline+uint64_t+rotr64+(uint64_t+n,+unsigned+int+c)%0A%7B%0A++const+unsigned+int+mask+%3D+(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(n)+-+1)%3B%0A%0A++//+assert+(+(c%3C%3Dmask)+%26%26%22rotate+by+type+width+or+more%22)%3B%0A++c+%26%3D+mask%3B%0A++return+(n%3E%3Ec)+%7C+(n%3C%3C(+(-c)%26mask+))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A//+clang+makes+a+mess+here,+and+fails+to+recognize+the+rotate+idioms+in+the+rotate+functions%0A//+using+actual+shift+and+OR+instructions.%0Aunsigned+long+rotate(unsigned+long+val,+unsigned+long+num,+unsigned+long+direction)%0A%7B%0A++++if+(direction)+%7B%0A++++++++return+rotl64(val,+num)%3B%0A++++++++++//return+_lrotl(val,+num)%3B%0A++++%7D+else+%7B%0A++++++++return+rotr64(val,+num)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.84007029876976,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:52.35803657362849,l:'4',m:70.92409240924093,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),k:47.64196342637151,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:70.92409240924093,n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:29.07590759075908,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:61.159929701230226,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)).  gcc has an interesting idea: rotate both ways and use a `cmov` to pick the right result.  This kinda sucks because variable-count shifts/rotates are 3 uops on Intel SnB-family CPUs.  (Because they have to leave the flags unmodified if the count turns out to be `0`.  See [the shift section of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter), all of it applies to rotates as well.)

Unfortunately BMI2 only added an immediate-count version of `rorx`, and variable-count `shlx`/`shrx`, not variable-count no-flags rotate.

---

**Anyway, based on those ideas, here's a good way to implement your function** for the x86-64 System V ABI / calling convention (where functions are allowed to clobber the input-arg registers and `r10` / `r11`).  I assume you're on a platform that uses the x86-64 SysV ABI (like Linux or OS X) because you appear to be using `rdi`, `rsi`, and `rdx` for the first 3 args (or at least trying to), and your `long` is 64 bits.

```
    ;; untested
    ;; rotate(val (rdi), num (rsi), direction (rdx))     
rotate:
    xor     ecx, ecx
    sub     ecx, esi        ; -num

    test    edx, edx
    mov     rax, rdi        ; put val in the retval register 

    cmovnz  ecx, esi        ; cl =  direction ? num : -num
    rol     rax, cl         ; works as a rotate-right by 64-num if direction is 0
    ret
```

xor-zero / sub is often better than mov / neg because the xor-zeroing is off the critical path.  `mov` / `neg` is better on Ryzen, though, which has zero-latency integer `mov` and still needs an ALU uop to do xor-zeroing.  But if ALU uops aren't your bottleneck, this is still fine.  It's a clear win on Intel Sandybridge (where `xor`-zeroing is as cheap as a NOP), and also a latency win on other CPUs that don't have zero-latency `mov` (like Silvermont/KNL, or AMD Bulldozer-family).

`cmov` is 2 uops on Intel pre-Broadwell.  A 2's complement bithack alternative to xor/sub/test/cmov might be just as good if not better.  `-num = ~num + 1`.

```
rotate:
    dec     edx             ; convert direction = 0 / 1 into  -1 / 0
    mov     ecx, esi        ; couldn't figure out how to avoid this with  lea  ecx, [rdx-1] or something

    xor     ecx, edx        ; (direction==0) ? ~num : num  ; NOT = xor with all-ones
    sub     ecx, edx        ; (direction==0) ? ~num + 1 : num + 0;
                            ; conditional negation using -num = ~num + 1.    (subtracting -1 is the same as adding 1)

    mov     rax, rdi        ; put val in the retval register 
    rol     rax, cl         ; works as a rotate-right by 64-num if direction is 0
    ret
```

This would have more of an advantage if inlined so `num` could already be in `ecx`, making this shorter than the other options (in code-size and uop count).

Latency on Haswell

- From `direction` being ready to `cl` being ready for `rol`:  3 cycles (`dec` / `xor` / `sub`).  Same as `test` / `cmov` in the other version.  (But on Broadwell/Skylake `test`/`cmov` only has 2 cycle latency from `direction` to `cl`)
- From `num` being ready to `cl` being ready: 2 cycles: `mov`(0) + `xor`(1) + `sub`(1), so there's room for `num` to be ready 1 cycle later.  This is better than with `cmov` on Haswell where it's `sub`(1) + `cmov`(2) = 3 cycles.  But on Broadwell/Skylake, it's only 2c either way.

The total front-end uop count is better on pre-Broadwell, because we avoid `cmov`.  We traded an `xor`-zeroing for a `mov`, which is worse on Sandybridge, but about equal everywhere else.  (Except that it's on the critical path for `num`, which matters for CPUs without zero-latency `mov`.)

BTW, a branching implementation could actually be faster if the branch on `direction` is very predictable.  But usually that means it would have been better to just inline a `rol` or `ror` instruction.

---

Or this one: gcc's output with the redundant `and ecx, 63` removed.  It should be pretty good on some CPUs, but doesn't have much advantage compared to the above.  (And is clearly worse on mainstream Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs including Skylake.)

```
;; not good on Intel SnB-family
;; rotate(val (rdi), num (rsi), direction (rdx))
rotate:
    mov     ecx, esi
    mov     rax, rdi

    rol     rax, cl         ; 3 uops
    ror     rdi, cl         ; false-dependency on flags on Intel SnB-family

    test    edx, edx        ; look at the low 32 bits for 0 / non-0
    cmovz   rax, rdi        ; direction=0 means use the rotate-right result
    ret
```

The false dependency is only for the flag-setting uops; I think the `rdi` result of `ror rdi,cl` is independent of the flag-merge uop of the preceding `rol rax,cl`. (See [SHL/SHR r,cl latency is lower than throughput](http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#860)).  But all the uops require p0 or p6, so there will be resource conflicts that limit instruction-level parallelism.

---

#### Using `rotate(unsigned long val, int left_count)`

Caller passes you a signed rotate count in `edi`.  Or call it `rdi` if you want; you ignore all but the low 6 bits of it, and you actually just do a left-rotate in the range `[0, 63`, but that's the same as supporting left and right rotates with range `[-63, +63]`.  (With larger values wrapping into that range).

e.g. an arg of `-32` is `0xffffffe0`, which masks down to `0x20`, which is 32.  Rotating by 32 in either direction is the same operation.

```
rotate:
    mov  rax, rdi
    mov  ecx, esi
    rol  rax, cl
    ret
```

The only way this could be any more efficient is inlining into the caller to avoid the `mov` and `call`/`ret` instructions.  (Or for constant-count rotates, using an immediate rotate count which makes it a single-uop instruction on Intel CPUs.)