# C++ encryption and decryption

Tags: c++, assembly

```
void encrypt_chars(int length)
{
    char temp_char;                 

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    
    {
        temp_char = OChars[i];          

        __asm {                         
            push   eax                  
            push   ecx                  

            movzx  ecx, temp_char       
            call   encrypt_nn           
            mov    temp_char, al        

            pop    ecx                  
            pop    eax                  
        }
        EChars[i] = temp_char;          
    }
    return;


    __asm {

    encrypt_nn:
        mov eax, ecx        
            inc eax 
            ret
    }
```

The encryption part is fine, but I thought I would copy and paste the code to the decryption and instead of incrementing I would decrement the values, so that it would go back and decrypt the data

---

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------- DECRYPTION ROUTINES -------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
void decrypt_chars(int length)
{
    char temp_char;                     

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i--)
    {
        temp_char = OChars[i];

        __asm {                     
            push   eax                  
            push   ecx                  

            movzx  ecx, temp_char       
            call   encrypt_nn           
            mov    temp_char, al        

            pop    ecx                   
            pop    eax              
        }
        EChars[i] = temp_char;      
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is assembly language not c++

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: so basicly you just take a character from an array and increment it by 1, then store the last half back into the array? that's not a very good encryption. basicly you would just have to dec ecx and you had the char back [edit: isn't this called "cesar's encryption"?]

Comment: yes I am trying to do cesar's encryption but I am not very good at assembly language.

Comment: Thanks I just noticed some of my mistake

Comment: Using a function call from inline asm seems crazy here.  You could write the char-increment and char-decrement loops in inline asm is about as many instruction.  Or you could write one function that uses +1 or -1 in a register, i.e. `add byte [mem], al` instead of `inc` / `dec`, so it's the same loop but adding a runtime variable number.  This is actually just as efficient.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter.

Comment: Your edit turned this into a totally separate question, which invalidates the answer.  (For the right answer (`lea`), ask a compiler to compile `int foo(int a) { return a+4; }` with a register-arg calling convention: https://godbolt.org/g/AR5EnG.

Comment: If you have another question, ask it separately instead of editing to change this into a very different question.  Anyway, you know you can `add eax, 4` instead of `inc eax` 4 times, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**

In order to do the opposite of your encryption operation, you should replace the call to encrypt_nn with a new routine that decrements instead of increments:

```
 __asm {

    decrypt_nn:
        mov eax, ecx        
            dec eax 
            ret
    }
```

**Comment:**

You have changed the loop statement from

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i--)
```

In the first case, loop will iterate through all values between `0` and `length-1`. This means you will iterate through your arrays of chars (assuming length is its size).

In the second case, you will get unpredictable behavior, since you are testing for `i < length` but doing `i--` in each loop iteration.
See more information [here](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: Actually it's unpredictable exactly what will happen with `i--` (unless you checked what MSVC actually does for this code), because [signed overflow is undefined behaviour in C++](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).  And the compiler can notice at compile time that it's inevitable if `length > 0` on function entry.  It could emit an illegal instruction so this function faults if it's ever executed.  Or it could emit code that assumes `length` must be non-positive, so the loop runs zero times.  i.e. UB implies a range limit.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment, I will fix my post