# Fractional Binary Subtraction Problem from CSAPP 3rd Practice Problem 2.51

Tags: c, binary

> What is the binary representation of 0.00011001100110011001101 − 0.0000000000000000000000000[1100]? Both numbers are represented using fractional binary number representation.

The solution given in my textbook is 0.0000000000000000000000000[1100].

I've tried to do

```
0.00011001100110011001101 - 0.000[1100]
```

following the binary subtraction rule (1 - 0 = 1, 0 - 1 = 1, 1 - 1 = 0, 0 - 0 = 0), the answer I got was nothing like the given solution. What is the correct way to do this kind of subtraction?

Note: This problem originates from CSAPP 3rd Practice Problem 2.51.

Comment: Where did you learn that 0-1=1?  Can you explain the reasoning behind this "rule"?

Comment: https://byjus.com/maths/binary-subtraction/

Comment: @CharlesZ. "_Service Unavailable in EU region_"

Comment: Sorry about that. The website stated that 0 - 1 = 1 because we can borrow from a potential 1 to the left of the current digit so that we can do 2 - 1 = 1.

Comment: I afraid you are mixing up different things. Also the "textbook" solution (as you quote it) looks very wrong, the result is most definitely negative.

Comment: Charles Z., "the answer I got was nothing like the given solution" --> what was your result and the given solution?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Sorry for the confusion. But 0.1 could be written as 0.000[1100], that why I wrote that right after the question.

Comment: Charles Z. Post is tagged [floating-point].  FP does not have repeated fractions like  0.000[1100].

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I should have been more clear on the format I used to represent those numbers. In this question, all numbers are represented using fractional binary number representation. In this format, 0.1 could only be represented using a nonterminating sequence 0.000[1100]. I hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: @CharlesZ. If "**all** numbers are represented using fractional binary number representation" is true then 0.1 (base 2) is same as 0.5 (base 10).    0.1 could only be represented using a nonterminating sequence 0.000[1100] contradicts.  Still, unclear why the [floating-point] tag as there are no repeating fractions there.

Comment: If this is the "global" edition of CS:APP, beware that its assembly-language practice problems were broken by incompetent / careless people hired by the publisher.  e.g. [CS:APP example uses idivq with two operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57998998).  This particular one might or might not be ok - the people who rewrote the problems seem to know some about computer architecture, but have big gaps in their x86-64 specifics, from what I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the binary representation of 0.00011001100110011001101 − 0.1?

Since the second is larger than the first, reverse the order

```
-(0.1 - 0.00011001100110011001101)

  0.10000000000000000000000 append zeroes
- 0.00011001100110011001101
---------------------------
  0.01100110011001100110011
```

Result -0.01100110011001100110011

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, using 1's complement subtraction:

```
  0.00011001100110011001101 (a)
− 0.10000000000000000000000 (b)
```

becomes:

```
     1111111111111111111111  (carry bits)
   0.00011001100110011001101 (copy of a)
 + 1.01111111111111111111111 (1's complement of b)
   =========================
   1.10011001100110011001100 (sum)
```

Then take the 1's complement of the result, and add a negative sign:

```
 -0.01100110011001100110011
```

I don't see any way to get their solution unless they're doing some special kind of truncated subtraction that doesn't allow negative values.

Comment: Why 1's complement subtraction, not unsigned binary?  Because of the repetition out to infinity, instead of being fixed-point?

Comment: @PeterCordes, because the page he linked showed the method using 1's complement.

Comment: Oh, you mean https://byjus.com/maths/binary-subtraction/, which the OP mentioned in comments, separate from the problem in their textbook.  And yeah, *If the result has a carryover, then add that carry over in the least significant bit* so they're just deferring the `+1` in the `~x + 1 = -x` identity, in case that step can be avoided when the final result is negative.

Comment: So it's not "1's complement subtraction" signed subtraction, it's *using* 1's complement -> binary addition as a method to implement plain binary subtraction.  Aka "**Binary Subtraction** *Using* / *by* 1’s Complement", as that link describes it.  As well as naming the process of flipping all the bits, "1's complement" is also the name of a signed-integer representation where that procedure on the bit-pattern negates the value represented.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement).  1's complement add/sub is *not* the same binary operation as normal add/sub, hence CPUs doing 2's comp