# how to get case number for jump table from a switch statement

Tags: c, assembly, x86, switch-statement, jump-table

I'm on this textbook, Randal E. Bryant, David R. O’Hallaron - Computer Systems. A Programmer’s Perspective [3rd ed.] (2016, Pearson)
and I am stuck at figuring out how the author is able to work out the case number for the switch table, as shown below~

What I am unsure about is how they obtain the case numbers like `Case A` is `Case 5`: and how `Case 2/7` is `Case C` and `Case D` , and so on for the rest of the cases in this example

Any help is appreciated thank you!!

[image: switch stmt]

[image: assembly code]

[image: Answer given]

Comment: In the jump table, the cases start at 0. So case 0 jumps to `.L3`. Cases 2 and 7 jump to `.L5`. Case 4 jumps to `.L6`. Case 5 jumps to `.L7`. Cases 1,3,6 and any number above 7, or below 0, jump to the `default` label, which is `.L2`.

Comment: The third image you posted contains an explanation for how they worked out the case numbers. So I'm not sure I understand your question. What did you find unclear about the explanation?

Comment: Is that perhaps CS:APP 3e global edition?  If so, that would explain the bugs in the practice problems like the mixed up calling convention mentioned in Daniel's answer.  See [CS:APP example uses idivq with two operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57998998) for details.  If not, then it's hopefully listed in the errata for the non-global edition. https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/errata.html.  Oh, yes, that problem is listed there, so probably you have a good edition and this is one of the small number of errata in that edition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, your **book has a mistake** - it says that "`a` in `%rsi`, `b` in `%rdi`" - but this is [not the standard x64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) and it is inconsistent with the rest of the assembly.

What the book **meant**:

- `%rdi` -> `a`, `%rsi` -> `b`, `%rdx` -> `c`, and `%rcx` -> `dest`

Moving on, let's understand what happens:

---

#### Default Code Block

The first two opcodes are:

```
cmpq $7, %rdi
ja .L2
```

`ja` is jump if above, i.e. if `a > 7` then go to `.L2` - which is at the end of the assembly. We can deduce that this is the `default` code block (it continues immediately to the end of the function) - and under `.L2` we have:

```
movq %rsi, %rdi
movq %rdi, %(rcx) ; this corresponds to *dest = val in C
```

so we can conclude that `%(rcx)` gets `%rsi`'s value in this case - in other words, in the default code block, `val = b`.

---

#### Switch Code Blocks

If our first `ja` above did not excute, then we `jmp *.L4(,%rdi,8)`. Since `a` is not above 7, we have eight possibilities - we can see in the `.L4` table that:

- If `a == 0` then we jump to `.L3`
- If `a == 1`, `a == 3`, or `a == 6`, we jump to `.L2` (**our default code block**, described above)
- If `a == 2` or `a == 7` we jump to `.L5`
- If `a == 4` we jump to `.L6`
- If `a == 5` we jump to `.L7`

---

#### .L3, or case 0

This block runs `leaq 112(%rdx), %rdi`, which simply has the effect of setting `%rdi` to `%rdx + 112` - which is `c + 112`. We then jump to the end of the function - we can conclude that `val = c + 112` in the `case 0` code block.

---

#### .L7, or case 5

This block runs `leaq (%rdx, %rsi), %rdi`, which sets `%rdi` to `%rdx + %rsi` (which is `c + b`) - and then calls `salq $2, %rdi`, which just shifts this value left by 2 bits - for a total value of `(c + b) << 2`. We then jump to the end of the function - we can conclude that `val = (c + b) << 2` in the `case 5` code block.

---

#### .L6, or case 4

Here we have jumped immediately to the end of the function, just calling the `movq %rdi, (%rcx)` opcode - which is effectively equivalent to setting `*dest = a`. We can conclude that in this case, `val = a`.

---

#### .L7, or case 5

This block runs `xorq $15, %rsi` - which is equivalent to `b ^= 15`. It then runs `movq %rsi, %rdx` - setting `c` to this value. We then continue straight into `.L3` described above - which sets `val = c + 112`. We can conclude that `.L7` is our fall-through switch case.

---

In general, reversing switch cases can be very straightforward - it mostly involves understanding how the jump table corresponds to different values in the compared register (notice here how several possible values of `a` mapped to the same jump in the table) - and understanding the fall-throughs between different switch cases.

Comment: That calling-convention register mixup in this one problem is listed in the errata,  https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/errata.html.  So hopefully that's not a sign of the CS:APP 3e global edition which is [a disaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998998/csapp-example-uses-idivq-with-two-operands)

Comment: Let's also note for the readers that `ja` is an unsigned compare, so negative long values will be "above" 7 and take the default.