# question about an assembly code correspondence to a C code practice question

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am doing an exercise from this question:

[image]

The solution is attached on the right hand side. I am just wondering is there a mistake in the solution in particular the part that I underlined?

Should line 7 be the following instead of the given underlined answer?
5(%rbx, %rcx), %rbx                Compute x += y + 5

based on the original C code on the left where in the while loop it has this:

x += y;
(*p ) += 5;

I thought there maybe a mistake in the solution? (the solution is the one that I underlined with red)

could someone comment? thank you

Comment: You're absolutely right. The solution matches the code in the comments. Looks like you got another case of a professor updating a book revision to extort money from the students and forgetting to update the solutions.

Comment: @littleadv: What's happening here is that the publisher of CS:APP 3e global edition hired some incompetent people to make up a different set of practice problems.  Notice the `idiv $9, %rcx` (which doesn't exist in x86-64), and use of qword operand-size for `short` types!  [CS:APP example uses idivq with two operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57998998) .  The commented logic not even matching the source code is yet another problem.  Basically a duplicate; the practice problems in that edition were made by people who don't know x86-64, apparently also carelessly / incompetently.

Comment: The claimed GCC output is hand-written, not actually from any GCC version (of course).  Don't trust it any farther than you can throw it.  The rest of the textbook is fine (and AFAIK quite good); only the practice problems were changed without consulting the authors.