# Practice 3.4 in CSAPP - move char to unsigned

Tags: c, assembly

In *CSAPP* exercise 3.4

```
src_t sp;
dest_t *dp;

*sp = (dest_t) dv;
```

When `src_t` is `char` and `dest_t` is `int`, the answer is

```
movsbl %al, (%edx)
movl %eax, (%rsi)
```

but when `src_t` is `char` and `dest_t` is `unsigned`, the answer is also

```
movsbl %al, (%edx)
movl %eax, (%rsi)
```

why ? I think my answer below is more correct:

```
movzbl %al, (%edx)
movl %eax, (%rsi)
```

which change the `movsbl` to `movzbl`, because the `unsigned`.

I tried to search for answers on the google.

Comment: Is this CS:APP 3e global edition?  The publisher had the practice problems rewritten by incompetent people that [just made stuff up without really knowing x86-64 asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998998/csapp-example-uses-idivq-with-two-operands).  None of these movs / movz instructions are valid with a memory destination, the source can be memory or register, but the destination must be a register. (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd is Intel-syntax documentation).  (AT&T syntax has the destination on the right, and `(%reg)` is a register indirect addressing mode.)

Comment: The signedness of the source is what matters when widening.  Consider a byte with bit-pattern `0xFF`.  If it's signed (representing `-1`), the appropriate `unsigned` value is `(unsigned)-1` = `0xFFFFFFFF` for 32-bit.  So `movsbl %al, %edx` / `mov %edx, (%rsi)` for `signed int` or `unsigned int *RSI` and source being `signed char AL`.  (Plain `char` is signed in standard x86 ABIs, unlike ARM for example.)  So it seems your question is not related to this invalid asm that stores to a 32-bit pointer and then reads from a register it didn't modify (EAX).