# How to change UP (direction) flag in x86 assembly to 1?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, flags, eflags

I want to change flag UP to one, now it is UP = 0. I am using Visual Studio 64-bit assembly.
(Intel calls this the "direction flag", DF).

I tried this:

```
.data
source DB 'Hello, world!', 0
byte_to_find DB 'o'
.code
MyProc1 proc
    std                     ; Set Direction Flag to 1 (backward direction)
    lea rdi, source         ; Load address of source string

    mov al, byte_to_find    ; Load byte to find into AL
    mov rcx, 13             ; Length of the source string

SearchLoop:
    scasb                   ; Compare AL with byte at [RSI]
    jne NotFound            ; Jump if not equal (byte not found)
    jmp ByteFound           ; Jump if equal (byte found)

NotFound:
    mov rax, 0              ; Set RAX to 0 (byte not found)
    jmp Done

ByteFound:
    mov rax, rdi            ; Store the address of the found byte in RAX
    dec rax                 ; Adjust RAX to point to the byte before the found byte
    jmp Done

Done:
    ret
MyProc1 endp
end
```

but when I was debugging nothing changed and there still was UP = 1. I also tried using only std and mov after that and there was the same issue.

Comment: If you want to search backwards you should set your pointer to the end of the string. Also as per calling convention, you should reset the direction flag before returning.

Comment: `scasb` scans for one element only, it should be prefixed by `repne`.

Comment: The comment on `scasb` is wrong, it doesn't use `rsi`. It uses `di`/`edi`/`rdi` depending on mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Searching forward using `scasb`** requires setting the direction flag DF to 0. The `cld` instruction does that. What it further requires is that you load the AL register with the character to be found, and the RDI register with the address of the **first** character of the string.

**Searching backward using `scasb`** requires setting the direction flag DF to 1. The `std` instruction does that. What it also requires is that you load the AL register with the character to be found, and the RDI register with the address of the **last** character of the string. Then the formula to use is:

```
RDI = AddressFirstChar + LengthString - 1
```

And if we plan to use the `repne` prefix, we also need to load the RCX register with the length of the string. You can write:

```
std                          ; Set DF to 1 (backward direction)
mov  al, byte_to_find        ; Load byte to find in AL
mov  ecx, 13                 ; Load length of the string in RCX
lea  rdi, [source + rcx - 1] ; Load address of last character in RDI
```

> ```
>   jne NotFound            ; Jump if not equal (byte not found)
>   jmp ByteFound           ; Jump if equal (byte found)
> NotFound:
> ```

You don't need both these jumps. Because the zero flag ZF has but two states, either it's 0 or 1, you can jump to *ByteFound* if ZF=1, and just fall-through in *NotFound* if ZF=0.

> ```
> SearchLoop:
>  scasb                   ; Compare AL with byte at [RSI]
>  jne NotFound            ; Jump if not equal (byte not found)
>  jmp ByteFound           ; Jump if equal (byte found)
> ```

Although you named this 'Search**Loop**', there's no actual loop here! After `scasb` has finished comparing the single byte in AL to the byte in memory at `es:[rdi]` you immediately jump to one of the two possible exits on the procedure. You need to repeat the `scasb` instruction either through prefixing this instruction with the `repne` prefix (REPeat while Not Equal):

```
  repne scasb
  je   ByteFound
NotFound:
```

or else by writing a normal loop:

```
SearchLoop:
  scasb
  je   ByteFound
  dec  rcx
  jnz  SearchLoop
NotFound:
```

> ```
> NotFound:
>   mov rax, 0   ; Set RAX to 0 (byte not found)
>   jmp Done
> ByteFound:
>   mov rax, rdi ; Store the address of the found byte in RAX
>   dec rax      ; Adjust RAX to point to the byte before the found byte
>   jmp Done
> Done:
>   ret
> ```

Some cleaning is required here, but especially your comment 'Adjust RAX to point to the byte *before* the found byte' is noteworthy.
I don't know why you would want to return the address **before** the find, but if that is indeed what you need then know that RDI is already pointing to before the found byte, so you wouldn't need that `dec rax`! And should you need to point at the find itself, you would rather have to increment the value:

```
NotFound:
  xor  eax, eax       ; Set RAX to 0 (byte not found)
  ret
ByteFound:
  lea  rax, [rdi + 1] ; Set RAX to point to the found byte
  ret
```

---

### Summary

#### Searching backward

```
  std                          ; Set DF to 1 (backward direction)
  mov  al, byte_to_find        ; Byte to find in AL
  mov  ecx, 13                 ; Length of the string in RCX
  lea  rdi, [source + rcx - 1] ; Address of last character in RDI
  repne scasb
  cld                          ; (*)
  je   ByteFound
NotFound:
  xor  eax, eax                ; Set RAX to 0 (byte not found)
  ret
ByteFound:
  lea  rax, [rdi + 1]          ; Set RAX to point to the find
  ret
```

(*) Whenever you need to use DF=1 locally, you should always return the direction flag to the clear state. Everybody expects to find DF=0, so we shouldn't have to bother using `cld` all the time! See [The probability of selected EFLAGS bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490225/the-probability-of-selected-eflags-bits).

#### Searching forward

```
  ; Save to assume DF=0 (forward direction)
  mov  al, byte_to_find  ; Byte to find in AL
  mov  ecx, 13           ; Length of the string in RCX
  lea  rdi, source       ; Address of first character in RDI
  repne scasb
  lea  rax, [rdi - 1]    ; Optimistically set RAX to point to the find
  je   Done              ; Byte found
NotFound:
  xor  eax, eax          ; Set RAX to 0 (byte not found)
Done:
  ret
```