# Why is __int128_t faster than long long on x86-64 GCC?

Tags: c++, performance, x86-64, cpu-architecture, integer-division

This is my test code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

using ll = long long;

int main()
{
    __int128_t a, b;
    ll x, y;

    a = rand() + 10000000;
    b = rand() % 50000;
    auto t0 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        a += b;
        a /= b;
        b *= a;
        b -= a;
        a %= b;
    }
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - t0).count() << ' '
         << (ll)a % 100000 << '\n';

    x = rand() + 10000000;
    y = rand() % 50000;
    t0 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        x += y;
        x /= y;
        y *= x;
        y -= x;
        x %= y;
    }
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - t0).count() << ' '
         << (ll)x % 100000 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This is the test result:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main -O2
$ ./main
2432 1
2627 1
```

Using GCC 10.1.0 on x64 GNU/Linux, no matter if it's using optimization of -O2 or un-optimized, `__int128_t` is always a little faster than `long long`.

`int` and `double` are both significantly faster than `long long`; `long long` has become the slowest type.

How does this happen?

Comment: I think it is irrelevant to `long long`. If you define `x` and `y` as `__int128_t` you will also get such difference https://godbolt.org/z/1e1YeE

Comment: To what degree can out of order execution affect the  results here? At a glance the two tests look completely independent of each other in which case isn't the processor free to execute them out of order? Asking to test my potentially naive understanding of the subject.

Comment: But even I do not use any optimization, the result is also the same.

Comment: I have tried define x,y as __int128_t and a,b as long long, the __int128_t is also faster than long long.

Comment: @Rich OOO won't execute two loops in parallel and probably because of the dependencies inside the loop code the OOO won't be very efficient here.

Comment: @xxhxx try to define everything as `__int128_t` and then everything as `long long`. You will see that the second loop is always slower

Comment: @AlexLop. I've tried what you said, the result is(Loop count is change to 5e7):
1603 1
1462 1

Comment: @xxhxx so you get difference anyway, which shouldn't be the case because both pieces of the code are identical. Probably this should be the question here.

Comment: @AlexLop. I also guess that's because different types of operations are in different order. But I have tried serveral orders to test, and `__int128_t` is always faster than `long long`.

Comment: @xxhxx https://godbolt.org/z/GznvoT here it is not...

Comment: @Rich: hardware OoO exec only works over short distances, where "short" is at most about 224 instructions on Skylake (the ROB size: https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/).  And that's measured along the path of execution, where each trip through the loop runs the loop body.    See [my answer here](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/350024).  Fusing the two loops would only be theoretically possible for an unconventional CPU like Transmeta Crusoe that internally does dynamic recompilation, not for current CPUs that look at instructions in execution order.

Comment: @AlexLop.: re: your first comment: That large difference between first and 2nd loops only happens with `-O2`, not `-O3`, and locally I can only repro a tiny difference with GCC10.1 on i7-6700k (SKL).  I suspect there's some other effect.  The recent microcode update that introduce a slowdown on JCC touching 32-byte boundaries probably doesn't explain it, front-end effects seem unlikely.  (But that's often my first thought for weird perf stuff, because IDK if compilers work around it yet).

Comment: But yeah, this craptastic benchmark doesn't do any warm-ups, so the only thing that saves it from CPU frequency and other warm-up effects totally throwing it off is that it runs a *lot* of iterations so that's a drop in the bucket.  [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987).  Also, it puts huge emphasis on division performance by doing it as much as other operations.  Very unrealistic for most use-cases.

Answer (score 42):

The performance difference comes from the **efficiency of 128-bit divisions/modulus** with GCC/Clang **in this specific case**.

Indeed, on my system as well as on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nMvdz9), `sizeof(long long) = 8` and `sizeof(__int128_t) = 16`. Thus operation on the former are performed by native instruction while not the latter (since we focus on 64 bit platforms). Additions, multiplications and subtractions are slower with `__int128_t`. But, built-in functions for divisions/modulus on 16-byte types (`__divti3` and `__modti3` on x86 GCC/Clang) are surprisingly faster than the native `idiv` instruction (which is pretty slow, at least on Intel processors).

If we look deeper in the implementation of GCC/Clang built-in functions (used only for `__int128_t` here), we can see that [`__modti3`](https://code.woboq.org/llvm/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/modti3.c.html) uses conditionals (when calling [`__udivmodti4`](https://code.woboq.org/llvm/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/udivmodti4.c.html#__udivmodti4)). **Intel processors** can execute the code faster because:

- taken **branches can be well predicted** in this case since they are always the same (and also because the loop is executed millions of times);
- the division/modulus is split in faster native instructions that can mostly be *executed in parallel by multiple CPU ports* (and that benefit from out-of-order execution). A `div` instruction is *still used* in most possible paths (especially in this case);
- The execution time of the `div`/`idiv` instructions covers most of the overall execution time because of their very **high latencies**. The `div`/`idiv` instructions cannot be executed in parallel because of the **loop dependencies**. However, the *latency of a `div` lower than a `idiv`* making the former faster.

Please note that the **performance** of the two implementations can **highly differ from one architecture to another** (because of the number of CPU ports, the branch prediction capability and the latency/througput of the `idiv` instruction).
Indeed, the [latency of a 64-bit `idiv` instruction](https://uops.info/table.html) takes 41-95 cycles on Skylake while it takes 8-41 cycles on AMD Ryzen processors for example. Respectively the latency of a `div` is about 6-89 cycles on Skylake and still the same on Ryzen. This means that the benchmark performance results should be significantly different on Ryzen processors (the opposite effect may be seen due to the additional instructions/branch costs in the 128-bits case).

Comment: Then why in this case `long long` performs faster? https://godbolt.org/z/GznvoT

Comment: @AlexLop. Maybe you read wrong? `long long` performs slower in this case.

Comment: @xxhxx Look at my link. I switched the order. The first loop works with `long long` type and its time ~300 vs. ~800

Comment: It reminds me this question which was asked some time ago... https://stackoverflow.com/q/62089260/5218277

Comment: @AlexLop I added some precision why the `long long` implementation can actually perform faster on some processors. On my Intel Skylake processor, I can confirm the results obtained of @xxhxx: the `__int128_t` version is about 10% *faster*, whatever the order of the loops. Your result is consistent with what I expect to see on a Ryzen processor due to the significantly lower latency of the `idiv`, do you have one?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I saw. Thank for the clarification. I already Upvoted your answer

Comment: re: `idiv r64` being very slow: [Can 128bit/64bit hardware unsigned division be faster in some cases than 64bit/32bit division on x86-64 Intel/AMD CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56655383) has some details, and specifically [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558274) shows an example where editing the binary to change REX.W into a dummy REX (changing `div rcx` into `div ecx` without changing anything else, even alignment) improved throughput by ~3x on Skylake.

Comment: But apparently AMD is fine with small numbers in wide registers, with `div r64` being about the same speed as `div r32`, if the numbers are the same.

Comment: You answer only explains why the extra instructions in the helper functions don't make it slower.  They don't explain why it's faster; if you single-step through `__modti3` and `__divti3`, you'll see that they run `div r8` or `div r9`.  The actual answer is that it's div not idiv, which is somewhat faster than `idiv` for 64-bit operand-size on Intel CPUs.  Those helper functions don't *manually* do division, they build extended-precision division out of `div r64` building blocks.  Small non-negative numbers are the simplest cast, reducing to only one division, but not zero.

Comment: It's still a 64-bit division; the helper functions don't check if the numbers are small enough to use `div r32` (they are, so this silly division-heavy benchmark would run much faster if you did that.)  After a few iterations, the numbers become small whatever the initial random `a` and `b` were.

Comment: @AlexLop.: [Why is ONE basic arithmetic operation in for loop body executed SLOWER THAN TWO arithmetic operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62089260) which you mentioned goes away with optimization enabled.  The effect there was 100% due to keeping vars in memory, and the quirks of Sandybridge-family variable latency for store forwarding, faster if you don't try too soon.  But in this one, the slower loop keeps everything in registers.  (So does the fast loop, except for the return address pushed by `call`, so there's no loop-carried dependency through memory.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right. It looked similar only from the first glance. Both cases have two consecutive `for` loops and both OP complained about unexpected performance degradation.

Comment: @AlexLop.: heh, almost every sloppy benchmark comparing 2 things has 2 timed regions with a for loop in each.  ([Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) explains why that can give wrong results without proper warm-up).  The bigger similarity here was the OP talking about un-optimized code and making a performance claim that isn't easily explained. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes I added more information about the `div`/`idiv` instructions and corrected the inaccuracies. Thank you for this very useful information!

Answer (score 32):

TL:DR: `__int128` division helper functions internally end up doing an unsigned `div reg64` (after some branching on the values being positive and the upper halves being `0`).  On Intel CPUs before Ice Lake, 64-bit `div` is faster than the signed `idiv reg64` that GCC inlines for signed `long long`.  Faster by enough to make up for all the extra overhead of the helper function, and extended-precision for the other operations.

You probably wouldn't see this effect on AMD CPUs: `long long` would be faster as expected because `idiv r64` is similar enough in perf to `div r64` there.

And `unsigned long long` is faster than `unsigned __int128` even on older Intel CPUs. For example on my i7-6700k (Skylake) at 3.9GHz (run under `perf stat` to be sure of CPU frequency during the test):

- 2097 (i128) vs. 2332 (i64)  - your original test (run back-to-back for CPU freq warm-up)
- 2075 (u128) vs. 1900 (u64)  - unsigned versions.  Slightly less branching in u128 division vs. i128, but major difference for i64 vs. u64 where the only difference is `div` vs. `idiv`.

Also, drawing any *general* conclusions from a very specific micro-benchmark like this would be a bad idea.  It is interesting to dig into why exactly the extended-precision `__int128` type manages to be faster in this division benchmark with positive numbers small enough to fit in a 32-bit integer, though.  (Fun fact: clang with some tuning options makes code to use 32-bit division if numbers fits in 32 bits, like if the high half of `dividend|divisor` is all-zero for unsigned.  This is worthwhile on older Intel, but shouldn't be on AMD, or Intel since Ice Lake.)

---

Your benchmark is *heavily* weighted towards division, which you do twice per iteration (`/` and `%`), even though it's *much* more expensive than other operations and in most code used much less often.  (e.g. sum a whole array then divide once to get the average.)

Your benchmark is also has no instruction-level parallelism: each step has a data dependency on the previous step.  This prevents auto-vectorization or anything that would show some of the advantages of narrower types, or the benefits of wider CPU pipelines like Alder Lake's 6 uops per cycle vs. Skylake's (or Core2's) 4 uops.  Similar widths in recent AMD, like [6 uops / clock in Zen 3 and 4](https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/), and in Zen 1 and 2 a limit of 5 instruction or 6 uops, whichever is less.

(It's also not careful to avoid warm-up effects like the first timed region being slow until the CPU gets up to max turbo.  [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987).  But that happens much faster than the couple seconds of your timed regions, so that's not a problem here.)

128-bit integer division (especially signed) is too complicated for GCC to want to inline, so gcc emits a call to a helper function, `__divti3` or `__modti3`.  (TI = tetra-integer, GCC's internal name for an integer that's 4x the size of `int`.)  These functions are documented in the [GCC-internals manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Integer-library-routines.html).

You can see the compiler-generated asm on [the Godbolt compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qj8zex).  i.e. 128-bit addition with add/adc, multiplication with one `mul` full-multiply of the low halves, and 2x non-widening `imul` of the cross products.  Yes these are slower than the single-instruction equivalents for `int64_t`.

But Godbolt doesn't show you the asm for libgcc helper functions.  It doesn't disassemble them even in "compile-to-binary" and disassemble mode (instead of the usual compiler asm text output) because it dynamically links libgcc_s instead of `libgcc.a`.

**Extended-precision signed division is done by negating if necessary and doing unsigned division of 64-bit chunks**, then fixing up the sign of the result if necessary.

With both inputs small and positive, no actual negation is needed (just testing and branching).  **There are also fast-paths for small numbers (high-half divisor = 0, and quotient will fit in 64 bits), which is the case here.**  The end result is that the path of execution through `__divti3` looks like this:

This is from manually single-stepping into the call to `__divti3` with gdb, after compiling with `g++ -g -O3 int128-bench.cpp -o int128-bench.O3` on my Arch GNU/Linux system, with gcc-libs 10.1.0-2.

```
# Inputs: dividend = RSI:RDI, divisor = RCX:RDX
# returns signed quotient RDX:RAX
|  >0x7ffff7c4fd40 <__divti3>       endbr64             # in case caller was using CFE (control-flow enforcement), apparently this instruction has to pollute all library functions now.  I assume it's cheap at least in the no-CFE case.
│   0x7ffff7c4fd44 <__divti3+4>     push   r12
│   0x7ffff7c4fd46 <__divti3+6>     mov    r11,rdi
│   0x7ffff7c4fd49 <__divti3+9>     mov    rax,rdx                                                                                                       │   0x7ffff7c4fd4c <__divti3+12>    xor    edi,edi
│   0x7ffff7c4fd4e <__divti3+14>    push   rbx
│   0x7ffff7c4fd4f <__divti3+15>    mov    rdx,rcx
│   0x7ffff7c4fd52 <__divti3+18>    test   rsi,rsi      # check sign bit of dividend (and jump over a negation)
│   0x7ffff7c4fd55 <__divti3+21>    jns    0x7ffff7c4fd6e <__divti3+46>
... taken branch to
|  >0x7ffff7c4fd6e <__divti3+46>    mov    r10,rdx
│   0x7ffff7c4fd71 <__divti3+49>    test   rdx,rdx      # check sign bit of divisor (and jump over a negation), note there was a mov rdx,rcx earlier
│   0x7ffff7c4fd74 <__divti3+52>    jns    0x7ffff7c4fd86 <__divti3+70>
... taken branch to
│  >0x7ffff7c4fd86 <__divti3+70>    mov    r9,rax
│   0x7ffff7c4fd89 <__divti3+73>    mov    r8,r11
│   0x7ffff7c4fd8c <__divti3+76>    test   r10,r10      # check high half of abs(divisor) for being non-zero
│   0x7ffff7c4fd8f <__divti3+79>    jne    0x7ffff7c4fdb0 <__divti3+112>  # falls through: small-number fast path
│   0x7ffff7c4fd91 <__divti3+81>    cmp    rax,rsi      # check that quotient will fit in 64 bits so 128b/64b single div won't fault: jump if (divisor <= high half of dividend)
│   0x7ffff7c4fd94 <__divti3+84>    jbe    0x7ffff7c4fe00 <__divti3+192>  # falls through: small-number fast path
│   0x7ffff7c4fd96 <__divti3+86>    mov    rdx,rsi
│   0x7ffff7c4fd99 <__divti3+89>    mov    rax,r11
│   0x7ffff7c4fd9c <__divti3+92>    xor    esi,esi
│  >0x7ffff7c4fd9e <__divti3+94>    div    r9                #### Do the actual division ###
│   0x7ffff7c4fda1 <__divti3+97>    mov    rcx,rax
│   0x7ffff7c4fda4 <__divti3+100>   jmp    0x7ffff7c4fdb9 <__divti3+121>
...taken branch to
│  >0x7ffff7c4fdb9 <__divti3+121>   mov    rax,rcx
│   0x7ffff7c4fdbc <__divti3+124>   mov    rdx,rsi
│   0x7ffff7c4fdbf <__divti3+127>   test   rdi,rdi     # check if the result should be negative
│   0x7ffff7c4fdc2 <__divti3+130>   je     0x7ffff7c4fdce <__divti3+142>
... taken branch over a neg rax / adc rax,0 / neg rdx
│  >0x7ffff7c4fdce <__divti3+142>   pop    rbx
│   0x7ffff7c4fdcf <__divti3+143>   pop    r12
│   0x7ffff7c4fdd1 <__divti3+145>   ret
... return back to the loop body that called it
```

[Intel CPUs (since IvyBridge) have zero-latency `mov`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all) (except for Ice Lake), so all that overhead doesn't worsen the critical path latency (which is your bottleneck) significantly. Or at least not enough to make up the difference between `idiv` and `div`.

The branching is handled by branch prediction and speculative execution, only checking the predictions after the fact when the actual input register values are the same.  The branching goes the same way every time so it's trivial for branch prediction to learn.  Since division is so slow, there's plenty of time for out-of-order exec to catch up.

64-bit operand-size integer division is very slow on Intel CPUs, even when the numbers are actually small and would fit in a 32-bit integer, and the extra microcode for signed integer division is even more expensive.

e.g. on my Skylake (i7-6700k), https://uops.info/ shows that ([table search result](https://www.uops.info/table.html?search=div%20(r64&cb_lat=on&cb_tp=on&cb_uops=on&cb_ports=on&cb_SKL=on&cb_ICL=on&cb_ZEN2=on&cb_measurements=on&cb_base=on)) )

- **`idiv r64` is 56 uops for the front-end, with latency from 41 to 95 cycles** (from divisor to quotient, which is the relevant case here I think).
- **`div r64` is 33 uops for the front-end, with latency from 35 to 87 cycles.** (for that same latency path).

The latency best-case happens for small quotients or small dividends or something, I can never remember which.

Similar to the branching that GCC does in software for 128-bit division in terms of 64-bit, I think the CPU microcode is internally doing 64-bit division in terms of narrower operations, probably the 32-bit that's only 10 uops for signed or unsigned, with much lower latency.  (Ice Lake improves the divider so 64-bit division isn't much slower than 32-bit.)

This is why you found `long long` so much slower than `int` for *this* benchmark.  In a lot of cases it's about the same, or half speed if memory bandwidth or SIMD are involved.  (Only 2 elements per 128-bit of vector width, not 4).

**AMD CPUs handle 64-bit operand size more efficiently, with performance only depending on the actual values, so about the same for div r32 vs. div r64 with the same numbers.**

BTW, the actual values tend to be something like `a=1814246614 / b=1814246613` = 1, then `a=1 % b=1814246612` (with `b` decreasing by 1 every iteration).  **Only ever testing division with quotient=1 seems very silly.**  (The first iteration might be different, but we get into this state for the 2nd and later.)

Performance of integer operations other than division is not data-dependent on modern CPUs.  (Unless of course there are *compile-time* constants that allow different asm to be emitted.  Like division by a constant is much cheaper when done with a multiplicative inverse calculated at compile time.)

re: `double`: see [Floating point division vs floating point multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125033/floating-point-division-vs-floating-point-multiplication/45899202#45899202) for division vs. multiplication.  FP division is often harder to avoid, and its performance is relevant in more cases, so it's handled better.

---

Related:

- [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983453/trial-division-code-runs-2x-faster-as-32-bit-on-windows-than-64-bit-on-linux/52558274#52558274) has a specific example of changing `div r64` to `div r32` in a program that uses small-enough numbers, and seeing throughput improve ~3x.
- [Can 128bit/64bit hardware unsigned division be faster in some cases than 64bit/32bit division on x86-64 Intel/AMD CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56655383) has some details about div and idiv being microcoded.
- [How sqrt() of GCC works after compiled? Which method of root is used? Newton-Raphson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642663/how-sqrt-of-gcc-works-after-compiled-which-method-of-root-is-used-newton-rap) has some hardware details of how div/sqrt execution units are designed in general, and in older Intel CPUs.  But that doesn't explain why 64-bit is so many more uops than 32-bit; I'm only inferring that the hardware must be narrower before Ice Lake from the fact that it needs so many more uops of microcode.