# Cpp uint32_fast_t resolves to uint64_t but is slower for nearly all operations than a uint32_t (x86_64). Why does it resolve to uint64_t?

Tags: c++, types, x86-64, abi, microbenchmark

Ran a benchmark and uint32_fast_t is 8 byte but slower than 4 byte uint32_t for nearly all operations. If this is the case why does uint32_fast_t not stay as 4 bytes?

OS info:
5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Cpu info:

```
cat /sys/devices/cpu/caps/pmu_name
skylake

model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
```

Benchmark I used for testing:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdint>

#define TEST_SIZE (1u << 26)

#define ADD(X, Y)     X += Y
#define SUB(X, Y)     X -= Y
#define MULT(X, Y)    X *= Y
#define DIV(X, Y)     X /= Y
#define MOD(X, Y)     X = X % Y
#define AND(X, Y)     X &= Y
#define OR(X, Y)      X |= Y
#define XOR(X, Y)     X ^= Y

// if you compile this make sure to have -DOP=<Operation macro name here>


#define bench_flush_all_pending()    asm volatile("" : : : "memory");
#define bench_do_not_optimize_out(X) asm volatile("" : : "r,m"(X) : "memory")

uint64_t inline __attribute__((always_inline)) __attribute__((const))
get_cycles() {
    uint32_t hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return (((uint64_t)lo) | (((uint64_t)hi) << 32));
}


constexpr uint32_t
size_ratio() {
    return sizeof(uint_fast32_t) / sizeof(uint32_t);
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./%s <A or B>\n", argv[0]);
    }
    uint_fast32_t * valsf32 =
        (uint_fast32_t *)calloc(TEST_SIZE, sizeof(uint_fast32_t));
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
        valsf32[i] = rand();
    }
    uint32_t * vals32 = (uint32_t *)valsf32;

    uint_fast32_t sinkf32   = rand();
    uint32_t      sink32    = rand();
    uint64_t      start, end;
    if (argv[1][0] == 'A') {
        start = get_cycles();
#ifndef DO_NOTHING
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
            OP(sinkf32, valsf32[i]);
        }
        bench_do_not_optimize_out(sinkf32);
        bench_flush_all_pending();
#endif
        end = get_cycles();
    }
    else if (argv[1][0] == 'B') {
        start = get_cycles();
#ifndef DO_NOTHING
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
            OP(sink32, vals32[size_ratio() * i]);
        }
        bench_do_not_optimize_out(sink32);
        bench_flush_all_pending();
#endif
        end = get_cycles();
    }
    else {
        bench_do_not_optimize_out(sinkf32);
        bench_do_not_optimize_out(sink32);
    }

    fprintf(stderr,
            "\t%s (%zu Bytes): %.2E \"Cycles\" Per operator\n",
            argv[1][0] == 'A' ? "Fast u32" : "Norm u32",
            argv[1][0] == 'A' ? sizeof(uint_fast32_t) : sizeof(uint32_t),
            ((double)(end - start)) / TEST_SIZE);
    free(valsf32);
}
```

I compiled this with:

```
g++ -O3 test_operations.cc -o test_ops -DOP=<Operation macro name here>
```

i.e to test addition:

```
g++ -O3 test_operations.cc -o test_ops -DOP=ADD
```

To get a baseline just include `-DDO_NOTHING`

I'm hoping someone could either explain the advantage of having uint32_fast_t as 8 bytes or something I missed in this benchmark so that I can actually get a good comparison.

The same holds with `-fno-unroll-loops`

Here is a example run:

```
Running: test_ADD Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.52E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_ADD Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 7.92E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_SUB Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.34E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_SUB Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 7.94E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_MULT Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 2.54E+00 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_MULT Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 1.26E+00 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_DIV Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 1.48E+01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_DIV Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 1.09E+01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_MOD Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 1.52E+01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_MOD Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 1.20E+01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_AND Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.30E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_AND Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 7.98E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_OR Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.30E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_OR Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 8.00E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_XOR Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.29E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_XOR Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 7.95E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_NOTHING Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 2.09E-07 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_NOTHING Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 2.09E-07 "Cycles" Per operator
```

updated initialization function:

```
    uint_fast32_t * valsf32 =
        (uint_fast32_t *)calloc(TEST_SIZE, sizeof(uint_fast32_t));
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
        valsf32[i] = (uint32_t)rand(); // rand max is already an int by why not
        valsf32[i] += (valsf32[i] == 0);
        assert(valsf32[i]);
    }
    uint32_t * vals32 = (uint32_t *)calloc(TEST_SIZE, sizeof(uint_fast32_t));
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
        vals32[size_ratio() * i] = (uint32_t)valsf32[i];
        vals32[size_ratio() * i] += (vals32[size_ratio() * i] == 0);
        assert(vals32[size_ratio() * i]);
        assert(vals32[size_ratio() * i] == valsf32[i]);
    }
```

Results:

```
Running: test_ADD Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.27E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_ADD Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 7.83E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_SUB Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.29E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_SUB Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 7.72E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_MULT Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 2.55E+00 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_MULT Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 1.28E+00 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_DIV Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 1.49E+01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_DIV Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 1.10E+01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_MOD Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 1.53E+01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_MOD Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 1.25E+01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_AND Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.35E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_AND Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 8.34E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_OR Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.31E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_OR Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 7.76E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_XOR Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 8.34E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_XOR Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 7.82E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_NOTHING Fast u32
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 1.79E-07 "Cycles" Per operator
Running: test_NOTHING Norm u32
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 1.79E-07 "Cycles" Per operator
```

To test memory bandwidth added a TOUCH operator:

```
#define TOUCH(X, Y) X = Y
```

Results of TOUCH:

```
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 1.05E+00 "Cycles" Per operator
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 1.04E+00 "Cycles" Per operator
```

Added:

```
#define THREE_WAY ((A * vals8[i] + B) * vals8[i] + C)
#define TW(X, Y) X ^= THREE_WAY
// A, B, C, vals8, and i are all define
...
    uint8_t * vals8 = (uint8_t *)calloc(TEST_SIZE, 1);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
        vals8[i] = rand();
    }
...
       if (argv[1][0] == 'A') {
        uint_fast32_t A = rand();
        uint_fast32_t B = rand();
        uint_fast32_t C = rand();
...
    else if (argv[1][0] == 'B') {
        uint32_t A = rand();
        uint32_t B = rand();
        uint32_t C = rand();
```

Result of OP=TW

```
    Fast u32 (8 Bytes): 2.01E+00 "Cycles" Per operator
    Norm u32 (4 Bytes): 9.48E-01 "Cycles" Per operator
```

Edit 6:
Added CPU info.

Comment: Curious, why `X = X % Y` and not `X %= Y`?

Comment: Have you checked the assembly for the compiled program in both cases?  It's possible that for some reason, the `uint32_t` variant is being optimized into SIMD instructions whereas the `uint32_fast_t` variant is not.

Comment: `uint32_fast_t` is fastest for many 32-bit operations, but not all.

Comment: @paddy I recompiled with -fno-unroll-loops and got same result. Checked the asm and its comparable for the two.

Comment: @chux none of the operations with uint32_fast_t are faster. Also didn't know ```%=``` was a legal operator :/

Comment: `uint32_t * vals32 = (uint32_t *)valsf32;` looks dodgy. May make for many `vals32[]` with the value of zero.

Comment: @Noah That are many more applications of  32-bit operations than the simply ones shown here.

Comment: @chux fair enough regarding more applications (though this is a lot of the important ones). why would the cast lead to 0s? the uint32_t iteration moves by ```2 * i``` to avoid that.

Comment: Individual processor differences can impact how optimizations are handled. Differing pipelining schemes, etc.. I'm not sure what the compiler relies on in selection a `..._fast_t` type, what the considerations are and whether there is a giant lookup tables for each variation of processor model, but the processor itself (along with a host of considerations) will determine what is natively handled "fastest".

Comment: The speed of `fast` tends to come from single operations done many times vs. normal ones when the larger overall operation uses about the same memory.  Here `fast` takes 2x memory _in the array_.  Try a benchmark employs a data set of the same size, but it is the intermediate operation are either fast or normal.

Comment: @chux this benchmark uses the same size arrays for ```fast``` and ```normal``` test. In the ```normal``` test it iterators by ```2 * i```

Comment: `OP(sink32, vals32[size_ratio() * i]);` uses half of the `vals32[]` array.  Less memory traffic.

Comment: @chux but since its iterating through the same amount of total memory how does that affect things? Still has the load all the same cache lines no? How would you suggest testing 8 byte vs 4 byte values with the same sized elements? Wouldn't the casting mess with the times?

Comment: "norm"  is  accessing 1/2 the memory of "fast"  "norm" is not iterating through the same amount of total memory, it skips every other element.  AFAICT, this in a bus bandwidth test than "nomr" v. "fast".

Comment: Perhaps `sink = (A*x[i] + B)*x[i] + C` where `A,B,C` are fast or norm.

Comment: @chux see edit about memory bandwidth, added a TOUCH test and the two are basically exactly ==

Comment: @chux what would the type of x be though? if its 4 bytes that favors norm because no cast and if 8 bytes favors fast? Would making it a char affect both equally?

Comment: `sink, x[]` as 32-bit/.  Perhaps more tomorrow GTG.

Comment: @chux see most recent edit.

Comment: `get_cycles () __attribute__((const))` is a bug!  Apparently inlining saves you from yourself, because `const` would [tell GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) that the return value depended only on the args.  (Which isn't true; the CPU's internal TSC is different between calls).  It would let GCC CSE multiple calls together and assume the difference was 0.  Best to just use the `__rdtsc()` intrinsic: [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567).

Comment: What CPU do you have?  I'm guessing AMD?  Intel CPUs before Ice Lake have 64-bit division much slower than 32-bit, even for the same input numbers.  [Can 128bit/64bit hardware unsigned division be faster in some cases than 64bit/32bit division on x86-64 Intel/AMD CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56655383) / [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52558274).  Micro-benchmark results are in general more interesting to future readers if you give hardware details.

Comment: And yes, `uint_fast32_t = uint64_t` in x86-64 glibc is a poor choice, IMO, not considering SIMD or memory bandwidth, code size of REX prefixes, or mul/div performance (which were worse for 64-bit even on early K8 when ABI choices were being made).  For `int_fast32_t` you can at least argue that avoiding the need for sign-extension to 64-bit when used as an array index is useful, but x86-64 zero-extends 32-bit operations for free.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for pointing out the ```__attribute__((const))``` bug. Updated with CPU info (```Skylake``` and ```model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz```
```