# How do I write Rust code which compiles to assembly which resembles that produced by GCC from C?

Tags: c, assembly, rust, x86-64, compiler-optimization

I have these two source files:

```rust
const ARR_LEN: usize = 128 * 1024;

pub fn plain_mod_test(x: &[u64; ARR_LEN], m: u64, result: &mut [u64; ARR_LEN]) {
    for i in 0..ARR_LEN {
        result[i] = x[i] % m;
    }
}
```

and

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define ARR_LEN (128 * 1024)

void plain_mod_test(uint64_t *x, uint64_t m, uint64_t *result) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_LEN; ++ i) {
        result[i] = x[i] % m;
    }
}
```

Is my C code a good approximation to the Rust code?

When I compile the C code on godbolt.org `x86_64 gcc12.2 -O3` I get the sensible:

```asm
plain_mod_test:
        mov     r8, rdx
        xor     ecx, ecx
.L2:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+rcx]
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        mov     QWORD PTR [r8+rcx], rdx
        add     rcx, 8
        cmp     rcx, 1048576
        jne     .L2
        ret
```

But when I do the same for `rustc 1.66 -C opt-level=3` I get this verbose output:

```asm
example::plain_mod_test:
        push    rax
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB0_10
        mov     r8, rdx
        xor     ecx, ecx
        jmp     .LBB0_2
.LBB0_7:
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx + 8], rdx
        mov     rcx, r9
        cmp     r9, 131072
        je      .LBB0_9
.LBB0_2:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx]
        mov     rdx, rax
        or      rdx, rsi
        shr     rdx, 32
        je      .LBB0_3
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        jmp     .LBB0_5
.LBB0_3:
        xor     edx, edx
        div     esi
.LBB0_5:
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx], rdx
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx + 8]
        lea     r9, [rcx + 2]
        mov     rdx, rax
        or      rdx, rsi
        shr     rdx, 32
        jne     .LBB0_7
        xor     edx, edx
        div     esi
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx + 8], rdx
        mov     rcx, r9
        cmp     r9, 131072
        jne     .LBB0_2
.LBB0_9:
        pop     rax
        ret
.LBB0_10:
        lea     rdi, [rip + str.0]
        lea     rdx, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        mov     esi, 57
        call    qword ptr [rip + core::panicking::panic@GOTPCREL]
        ud2
```

How do I write Rust code which compiles to assembly similar to that produced by gcc for C?

---

Update: When I compile the C code with `clang 12.0.0 -O3` I get output which looks far more like the Rust assembly than the GCC/C assembly.

i.e. This looks like a GCC vs clang issue, rather than a C vs Rust difference.

```asm
plain_mod_test:                         # @plain_mod_test
        mov     r8, rdx
        xor     ecx, ecx
        jmp     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_6:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx + 8], rdx
        add     rcx, 2
        cmp     rcx, 131072
        je      .LBB0_8
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx]
        mov     rdx, rax
        or      rdx, rsi
        shr     rdx, 32
        je      .LBB0_2
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        jmp     .LBB0_4
.LBB0_2:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
        xor     edx, edx
        div     esi
.LBB0_4:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx], rdx
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx + 8]
        mov     rdx, rax
        or      rdx, rsi
        shr     rdx, 32
        jne     .LBB0_6
        xor     edx, edx
        div     esi
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx + 8], rdx
        add     rcx, 2
        cmp     rcx, 131072
        jne     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_8:
        ret
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid inserting boundary checks & code panic handling? that certainly takes a lot of instructions

Comment: you may consider raw pointers instead of arrays too. But the real answer is probably because gcc 12 C to asm backend is way more advanced than the rust LLVM counterpart

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre don't think it's a factor of how "advanced" the backend is, clang produces about the same output to GCC under `-Os`, and a similar one under `-Oz`. It just makes completely different decisions than GCC at O2/O3.

Comment: On the rust side, Os has no real effect, and `panic=abort` doesn't change anything. This is for the test that `m` is non-zero (`test rsi rsi`) in order to trigger a userland panic/abort, which I don't think you can disable at all. I'm not sure bounds checks are even involved, since the number of iterations is known at compile time (nor does switching the code to iterators change anything). I'd assume it's rather that the C compilers can lean a lot more into UBs to ignore a bunch of case Rust has to handle, but my asm skills are not strong enough to decipher the output at a glance.

Comment: I think the GCC output is a straightforward encoding of the loop (1 assignment per iteration), whereas the LLVM output is an encoding of a loop that does 2 assignments per iteration, complete with the state machinery to handle even/odd cases. Kind of strange that LLVM appears to not notice that 128 x 1024 is divisible by 2, though...

Comment: @virchau13: It's only checking the loop counter every 2 iterations, and not checking it being odd.  There's tail-duplication of the exit condition.  LLVM is inventing conditional branches within each iteration, and laying out that branching in "interesting" ways, though, not really committing to the small-number case being the fast path with fewer taken branches.  (See my answer for what it's actually branching on)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don’t compare apples to orange crabs.

Most of the difference between the assembly outputs is due to loop unrolling, which the LLVM code generator used by rustc does much more aggressively than GCC’s, and working around a CPU performance pitfall, [as explained in Peter Cordes’ answer](/a/74836933/3840170).  When you compile the same C code with Clang 15, it outputs:

```asm
        mov     r8, rdx
        xor     ecx, ecx
        jmp     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_6:
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx + 8], rdx
        add     rcx, 2
        cmp     rcx, 131072
        je      .LBB0_8
.LBB0_1:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx]
        mov     rdx, rax
        or      rdx, rsi
        shr     rdx, 32
        je      .LBB0_2
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        jmp     .LBB0_4
.LBB0_2:
        xor     edx, edx
        div     esi
.LBB0_4:
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx], rdx
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx + 8]
        mov     rdx, rax
        or      rdx, rsi
        shr     rdx, 32
        jne     .LBB0_6
        xor     edx, edx
        div     esi
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx + 8], rdx
        add     rcx, 2
        cmp     rcx, 131072
        jne     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_8:
        ret
```

which is pretty much the same as the Rust version.

Using Clang with `-Os` results in assembly much closer to that of GCC:

```asm
        mov     r8, rdx
        xor     ecx, ecx
.LBB0_1:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx]
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx], rdx
        inc     rcx
        cmp     rcx, 131072
        jne     .LBB0_1
        ret
```

Likewise does `-C opt-level=s` with rustc:

```asm
        push    rax
        test    rsi, rsi
        je      .LBB6_4
        mov     r8, rdx
        xor     ecx, ecx
.LBB6_2:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rcx]
        xor     edx, edx
        div     rsi
        mov     qword ptr [r8 + 8*rcx], rdx
        lea     rax, [rcx + 1]
        mov     rcx, rax
        cmp     rax, 131072
        jne     .LBB6_2
        pop     rax
        ret
.LBB6_4:
        lea     rdi, [rip + str.0]
        lea     rdx, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        mov     esi, 57
        call    qword ptr [rip + core::panicking::panic@GOTPCREL]
        ud2
```

Of course, there is still the check if `m` is zero, leading to a panicking branch.  You can eliminate that branch by narrowing down the type of the argument to exclude zero:

```rust
const ARR_LEN: usize = 128 * 1024;

pub fn plain_mod_test(x: &[u64; ARR_LEN], m: std::num::NonZeroU64, result: &mut [u64; ARR_LEN]) {
    for i in 0..ARR_LEN {
        result[i] = x[i] % m
    }
}
```

Now the function will emit identical assembly to Clang.

Answer (score 5):

`rustc` uses the LLVM back-end optimizer, so compare against `clang`.  LLVM unrolls small loops by default.

Recent LLVM is also tuning for Intel CPUs before Ice Lake, where `div r64` is *much* slower than `div r32`, so much slower that it's worth branching on.

**It's checking if a `uint64_t` actually fits in `uint32_t` and using 32-bit operand-size for `div`.**  The `shr`/`je` is doing `if ((dividend|divisor)>>32 == 0) use 32-bit` to check the high halves of both operands for being all zero.  If it checked the high half of `m` once, and made 2 versions of loop, the test would be simpler.  But this code will bottleneck on division throughput anyway.

---

This opportunistic `div r32` code-gen will eventually become obsolete, as Ice Lake's integer divider is wide enough not to need way more micro-ops for 64-bit, so performance just depends on the actual values, regardless of whether there are an extra 32 bits of zeros above it or not.  AMD has been like that for a while.

But Intel sold a *lot* of CPUs based re-spins of Skylake (including Cascade Lake servers, and client CPUs up to Comet Lake).  While those are still in widespread use, LLVM `-mtune=generic` should probably keep doing this.

For more details:

- [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983453/trial-division-code-runs-2x-faster-as-32-bit-on-windows-than-64-bit-on-linux/52558274#52558274) (a case where we know at compile-time the 64-bit integers will only hold small values, and rewriting the binary to use 32-bit operand-size with zero other changes to alignment or machine code makes it 3x faster on my Skylake CPU.)
- [uops for integer DIV instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63153788/uops-for-integer-div-instruction)
- [Can 128bit/64bit hardware unsigned division be faster in some cases than 64bit/32bit division on x86-64 Intel/AMD CPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655383/can-128bit-64bit-hardware-unsigned-division-be-faster-in-some-cases-than-64bit-3)