# Division performance for a x32 ELF on a x64 OS

Tags: c, windows, performance, x86, division

In the following example running a 32-bit ELF on a 64-bit architecture is faster and I don't understand why. I have tried with two examples one using a division the other one with a multiplication. The performance is as expected, however, the performance for the division is surprizing.

We see on the assembly that the compiler is calling `_alldiv` which emulates a 64-bit division on a 32-bit architecture, so it must be slower than simply using the assembly instruction `idiv`. So I don't understand the results I got:

My setup is: Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 2019

To time the code I use `Measure-Command { .\out.exe }`:

- Multiplication

  - 32-bit ELF: 3360 ms
  - 64-bit ELF: 1469 ms
- Division

  - 32-bit ELF: 7383 ms
  - 64-bit ELF: 8567 ms

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <Windows.h>

volatile int64_t m = 32;
volatile int64_t n = 12;
volatile int64_t result;

int main(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << 30); i++)
    {
#       ifdef DIVISION
        result = m / n;
#       else 
        result = m * n;
#       endif
        m += 1;
        n += 3;
    }
}
```

#### 64-bit disassembly (division)

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << 30); i++)
00007FF60DA81000  mov         r8d,40000000h  
00007FF60DA81006  nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  
    {
        result = m / n;
00007FF60DA81010  mov         rcx,qword ptr [n (07FF60DA83038h)]  
00007FF60DA81017  mov         rax,qword ptr [m (07FF60DA83040h)]  
00007FF60DA8101E  cqo  
00007FF60DA81020  idiv        rax,rcx  
00007FF60DA81023  mov         qword ptr [result (07FF60DA83648h)],rax  
        m += 1;
00007FF60DA8102A  mov         rax,qword ptr [m (07FF60DA83040h)]  
00007FF60DA81031  inc         rax  
00007FF60DA81034  mov         qword ptr [m (07FF60DA83040h)],rax  
        n += 3;
00007FF60DA8103B  mov         rax,qword ptr [n (07FF60DA83038h)]  
00007FF60DA81042  add         rax,3  
00007FF60DA81046  mov         qword ptr [n (07FF60DA83038h)],rax  
00007FF60DA8104D  sub         r8,1  
00007FF60DA81051  jne         main+10h (07FF60DA81010h)  
    }
}
```

#### 32-bit disassembly (division)

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1 << 30); i++)
00A41002  mov         edi,40000000h  
00A41007  nop         word ptr [eax+eax]  
    {
        result = m / n;
00A41010  mov         edx,dword ptr [n (0A43018h)]  
00A41016  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[00A4301Ch]  
00A4101B  mov         esi,dword ptr [m (0A43020h)]  
00A41021  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0A43024h]  
00A41027  push        eax  
00A41028  push        edx  
00A41029  push        ecx  
00A4102A  push        esi  
00A4102B  call        _alldiv (0A41CD0h)  
00A41030  mov         dword ptr [result (0A433A0h)],eax  
00A41035  mov         dword ptr ds:[0A433A4h],edx  
        m += 1;
00A4103B  mov         eax,dword ptr [m (0A43020h)]  
00A41040  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0A43024h]  
00A41046  add         eax,1  
00A41049  mov         dword ptr [m (0A43020h)],eax  
00A4104E  adc         ecx,0  
00A41051  mov         dword ptr ds:[0A43024h],ecx  
        n += 3;
00A41057  mov         eax,dword ptr [n (0A43018h)]  
00A4105C  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0A4301Ch]  
00A41062  add         eax,3  
00A41065  mov         dword ptr [n (0A43018h)],eax  
00A4106A  adc         ecx,0  
00A4106D  mov         dword ptr ds:[0A4301Ch],ecx  
00A41073  sub         edi,1  
00A41076  jne         main+10h (0A41010h)  
    }
}
```

### Edit

To investigate further as [Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd), I have slightly modified my code as follow:

```
volatile int64_t m = 32000000000;
volatile int64_t n = 12000000000;
volatile int64_t result;
```

This time I have these results:

- Division

  - 32-bit ELF: 22407 ms
  - 64-bit ELF: 17812 ms

Comment: Be curious of the dump of _alldiv to see what it is doing?  Could be a cached table of divides for small integer.  idiv is a known pig on x86 so perhaps that is faster?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It seems `__alldiv` is: http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/lldiv.asm.html

Comment: Double check that optimizations were turned on for this build?

Comment: The only way i see this being faster is if the integer multiplier was smart enough to change those divides into fixed point muls.  I am stumped.

Comment: MSVC can make ELF executables?  WSL can't even run 32-bit Linux/ELF executables (only x86-64), so how did you even run this?  Also, why introduce a store/reload memory dependency by making both input variables `volatile` as well as incrementing them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reasoning behind x64 having such a different performance result from x86?](//stackoverflow.com/q/44556614) where it mostly boils down to 32-bit code checking and using one 32-bit `div` instead of one 64-bit `div` for those input numbers.  But that question has many levels of libraries and JIT to wade through before getting to that issue.

Comment: @nowox: Slightly OT note: In case you don't know it already, you should have a look at Agner Fog's homepage: https://agner.org/optimize/. It contains a lot of valueable resources regarding this topic...

Comment: Why are you using the term "[ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)"?  That's the name of an executable format used on Linux and Unix.  Is that just a typo for EXE / executable?  Windows uses the PE/COFF executable format for normal Windows `.exe` files like you're probably making, not ELF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [instruction timings for x86 processors](https://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf), it turns out that on recent Intel processors, a 64-bit divide is 3-4x as expensive as a 32-bit divide -- and if you look at the internals of alldiv (link in the comments above), for your values which will always fit in 32 bits, it will use a single 32-bit divide...

Comment: [Clang has the same capability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54438477/995714) and will check if the operands fit in 32 bits to use the 32-bit div

Comment: Near duplicate for 64-bit `div` being much slower than 32-bit `div` on Intel CPUs: [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](//stackoverflow.com/q/29983453).