# Fastest way to strip trailing zeroes from an unsigned int

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation

Suppose we are trying to remove the trailing zeroes from some unsigned variable.

```
uint64_t a = ...
uint64_t last_bit = a & -a; // Two's complement trick: last_bit holds the trailing bit of a
a /= last_bit; // Removing all trailing zeroes from a.
```

I noticed that it's faster to manually count the bits and shift. (MSVC compiler with optimizations on)

```
uint64_t a = ...
uint64_t last_bit = a & -a;
size_t last_bit_index = _BitScanForward64( last_bit );
a >>= last_bit_index
```

Are there any further quick tricks that would make this even faster, assuming that the compiler intrinsic `_BitScanForward64` is faster than any of the alternatives?

Comment: Can't you use `_BitScanForward64` directly on `a`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62227706/how-to-remove-trailing-zeros-from-a-binary-number)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On x86, `_tzcnt_u64` is a faster alterative of `_BitScanForward64`, if it is available (it is available with BMI instruction set).

Also, you can directly use that on the input, you don't need to isolate lowest bit set, as pointed out by @AlanBirtles in a comment.

Other than that, noting can be done for a single variable. For an array of them, there may be a SIMD solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::countr_zero`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_zero) (c++20) and rely on the compiler to optimize it.

```
a >>= std::countr_zero(a);
```

<sup>(bonus: you don't need to specify the width and it works with any unsigned integer type)</sup>