# std::unordered_map vs std::map have different performances depending on the compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, unordered-map, stdmap, google-benchmark

I have integer keys which have to be associated to `std::vector<T>`, with `T` an iterator-like object (you can safely assume each element of the vector is a pointer).

The obvious candidate from the STL is a `std::unordered_map<int,vector<T>>`, mainly because I should not get hash collisions as my keys are just integers. In my particular case each key maps to a vector with potentially "many" elements which are pushed  back. To give an example with a `std::unordered_map<int,vector<double>>`

```
constexpr size_t map_size = 360;
constexpr size_t vec_size = 1000;

std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<double>> grid_unmap_int;
for (size_t i = 0; i < map_size; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < vec_size; ++j)
      {
        grid_unmap_int[i].push_back(j);
      }
  }
```

If I compare the performance of the insertion using the code above with a `std::map<int,std::vector<double>>`, I get quite different results which seems to depend on the chosen compiler. In particular, the result for the `std::unordered_map` using clang turns out to be much faster. **Why does the unordered_map behaves so poorly with GCC ?** I am afraid it's related to the fact my values are vector with no known size...

Here's a link to quick_bench: https://quick-bench.com/q/fgQ9XuZ9tmeXcKYEGuJOW165FtE

Here are the associated results (-std=c++17 and -O3)
Output with ***GCC 9.4***:
[image]

Output with ***CLANG 14.0***:
[image]

Comment: The C++ standard specifies complexity, nothing else. How performant an implementation is depends on the implementation itself.

Comment: I also recommend you set the vector capacity before your `push_back` loop, to see if it makes any difference. Because right now you're benchmarking not only the map performance, but also the reallocation performance of `std::vector` (which is probably the largest contributor to your performance).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, that's the question.  Both compilers are using libstdc++ (their screenshot shows the clang version wasn't set to use libc++), so it's the *same* C++ implementation of those classes, compiled by different compilers, unless header versions differ.  And they're asking why those compilers make differently-performing asm for the x86-64 cloud instances Quick-Bench runs them on.  At least I hope they realize that's what the question boils down to.

Comment: Yes, it's implementation-dependent, but what I'd like to understand is indeed what is the reason for that slowdown.

Comment: The reallocation was actually intentional because in my case I don't even have an estimate for the capacity.

Comment: I'm curious if the quick-bench empty-loop baseline ran the same speed on both runs; if so, GCC's `std::map` was over 3x faster than clang's.  Would be worth trying on an idle desktop where we don't have to worry about different runs being on different cloud hardware, and on different levels of competing load (which quick-bench tries to factor out by only showing performance relative to an empty loop that it tested on the same instance.)

Comment: @PeterCordes *Both compilers are using libstdc++ (their screenshot shows the clang version wasn't set to use libc++), so it's the same C++ implementation of those classes* We' can't be sure that clang 14 uses libstdc++ of GCC 9.4, so your statement is not correct.

Comment: I can reproduce these results on my system: clang's umap in about 1.81 ms/iter, gcc's in about 5.3 ms/iter.  clang's map in about 7.3 ms/iter, gcc's in 3.75 ms/iter.  This is on my i7-6700k running Arch Linux with gcc13.2.1 and clang 16.0.6, with `-O3` and no other options (Adding [How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646) which might be relevant for my CPU sped up clang's umap to 1.73ms, others changed less).  I confirmed with `strace -o clang.trace -f -e openat clang++ ...` that clang was using the same headers as GCC.

Comment: After `perf record` / `perf report` for each build, I'm seeing GCC's `std_umap` has two 64-bit `div rcx` instructions both taking a lot of time. (47% and 39% each).  And it's doing `cvtsi2sd xmm0,rbp` like the source.  But Clang is only doing one `div` with 32-bit operand-size (*[Why does Clang do this optimization trick only from Sandy Bridge onward?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54438477)*), which is *much* faster on Intel before Ice Lake such as my Skylake. And it's doing some SIMD FP math, probably strength-reduction on the int->double conversion to just add 1, but I haven't followed it all

Comment: Is it intentional that your benchmark appends to the same bucket inside the inner loop, giving the compiler a chance to hoist the `map`/`unordered_map` lookup and just grow a `std::vector`?  Or at least reuse the hash, if it's not fully hoisting.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly to know what the compiler really does in each case?