# clang: Is there a way to specify low level instructions used in c11 atomic operations?

Tags: c, x86, clang, atomic, compiler-optimization

**Can I tell clang to "use xxx instructions" or "don't use yyy instructions" for built-in or C11 atomic operations (suppose there is an alternative)?**

[edit] the microbenchmark that can reproduce the performance regression: [a naive rwlock](https://github.com/wuxb45/atomictest).

It all began with a recent upgrade to clang 9.0. There are some performance regressions in my program so I tried to inspect the instructions generated. Surprisingly clang has changed a lot on what instructions to use for the atomic functions (c11's `atomic_fetch_{add,sub}` on x86_64).

With clang 8, it all generates `lock addl` and `lock subl`. But clang 9 switched to `lock incl` and `lock decl` for +1 and -1, and `lock xadd` for other numbers (at least for addition. I didn't check if there was an xsub, or subl is still there).
The inc/xadd/add instructions usually has same speed but in certain scenarios I observed better efficiency with `lock addl`. Anyway, I'm not going to discuss if one insn can be faster than the other. Since clang 8 used one, there better be a way to continue using it.

I tried to use inline assembly to force the use of `lock addl` but it's hard to fully exploit the efficiency as inline assembly prevents some optimizations. The ideal solution is to tell the compiler to do it the old way.

*I'm not posting any code here because the question is not about improving performance. But I'd like to share the code for anyone who is willing to verify the performance issue.*

[update] I tested it on both Broadwell and Skylake. The performance regression is only visible with certain workloads. I'm not sure if it's actually related to the instructions or the way clang8/9 do optimizations.

Comment: `xsub` does not exist so clang can't use that, it uses `lock xadd` with a negative value

Answer (score 1):

You can report the performance regression on clang's bug tracker, especially if you can produce a MCVE / [mcve] that's slower with GCC9 for the same reason as your main code.

You can't generally force the compiler's instruction-selection choices without fully doing it yourself with inline asm.

**But tuning options can be relevant**, e.g. `-march=native` to tune for your hardware.  (`-march=haswell`, or `-march=native` *on* a haswell, for example sets `-mtune=haswell` as well as enabling all the ISA extensions you have.)

e.g. gcc or clang will sometimes avoid `inc` in general, but use it when compiling for a specific CPU that doesn't have a problem with it.  (Not talking about the `lock` version, just `inc reg`).

**It looks like that's the case here: using `-march=skylake` gets clang9.0 to use `lock inc` instead of `lock add [mem], 1`, but it didn't with clang8.0 on Godbolt.**  (With just `-O3`, clang9.0 still uses `lock add`/sub)

`inc reg` is good on modern x86 (except for Silvermont / KNL), but `inc mem` (without lock) costs an extra uop on Intel CPUs: no micro-fusion of the load+add uops, only the store part (https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/).  IDK if it's also worse with `lock inc` vs. `lock add` or if you're seeing some other effect.  [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510095/inc-instruction-vs-add-1-does-it-matter/36510865#36510865)

**According to https://uops.info/, [`lock add m32, imm8`](https://www.uops.info/html-instr/ADD_LOCK_M32_I8.html) has *identical* uop count (8), latency and throughput to [`lock inc m32`](https://www.uops.info/html-instr/INC_LOCK_M32.html) on Skylake.**  On Haswell there's one fewer back-end uop, like the difference without a lock prefix.  But it's unlikely that affects throughput.  I didn't check other uarches and you didn't say what CPU you had.

I wouldn't really recommend `-march=skylake -mtune=generic`: it might fix *this* code-gen issue but might lead to worse tuning decisions in the rest of your code.  Except it doesn't even work, I guess clang is different from GCC in how it handles arch and tune options.  I guess you could avoid march options entirely and leave `-mtune` at the default, and just enable `-mavx2 -mfma -mpopcnt -mbmi -mbmi2 -maes -mcx16` and any other relevant ISA extensions your CPU has.

---

> and `lock xadd` for other numbers (at least for addition...

### Are you sure you still enabled optimization for the new compiler?

When the result of `--*p` or `atomic_fetch_add(p, -2)` is unused, clang 9.0 still uses `lock dec` or `lock sub`.  I can only get clang to use `lock xadd` if I disable optimization, making the surrounding code into total garbage.

Or with optimization enabled, by returning the result.  IDK, maybe in more complex functions, clang9.0 changed something that means it's not finding the same optimizations in your code, and using `lock xadd` to get the old value into a register.  Like maybe to return it to a caller that ignores it, if it decided not to inline as aggressively.

`lock xadd` is definitely slower than `lock add` or `lock sub`, but clang doesn't use it unless it has to (or if you disable optimization).

**asm output for clang8.0 `-O3 -march=skylake` vs. clang9.0 `-O3 -march=skylake`** (not including a `ret`)  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdatomic.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+incmem(int+*p)+%7B+%2B%2B*p%3B+%7D%0A%0Avoid+atomic_inc(_Atomic+int+*p)+%7B+%2B%2B*p%3B+%7D%0A%0Avoid+atomic_dec(_Atomic+int+*p)+%7B+--*p%3B+%7D%0A%0A//+result+still+unused,+but+unlike+--+clang+-O0+uses+lock+xadd%0Avoid+atomic_dec2(_Atomic+int+*p)+%7B%0A++++atomic_fetch_add(p,+-2)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+fetch_dec(_Atomic+int+*p)+%7B+return+--*p%3B+%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:31.538839911617607,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:35.12782675504907,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall++-mtune%3Dgeneric+-march%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

void incmem(int *p) { ++*p; }
    clang8:     addl   $1, (%rdi)       clang9:  incl    (%rdi)

void atomic_inc(_Atomic int *p) { ++*p; }
    clang8: lock addl  $1, (%rdi)       clang9: lock incl (%rdi)

void atomic_dec(_Atomic int *p) { --*p; }
    clang8: lock subl  $1, (%rdi)       clang9: lock decl (%rdi)

void atomic_dec2(_Atomic int *p) {
    atomic_fetch_add(p, -2);
}
    clang8: lock addl  $-2, (%rdi)      clang9: lock addl $-2, (%rdi)


// returns the result
int fetch_dec(_Atomic int *p) { return --*p; }
    clang8:                                    clang9:
        movl  $-1, %eax                            movl  $-1, %eax
        lock xaddl   %eax, (%rdi)                  lock  xaddl %eax, (%rdi)
        addl  $-1, %eax                            decl    %eax
        retq
```

With optimization disabled, we get clang 8 and 9 making literally identical code with `-O0 -march=skylake`:

```
# both clang8 and 9 with  -O0 -march=skylake
atomic_dec2:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        movl    $-2, -12(%rbp)
        movl    -12(%rbp), %ecx
        lock    xaddl   %ecx, (%rax)      # even though result is unused
        movl    %ecx, -16(%rbp)
        popq    %rbp
        retq
```

Comment: Appreciate it! I'll soon report it to the clang/llvm mailing list.

Comment: @Nybble: submit it on https://bugs.llvm.org as a missed-optimization aka performance bug, if you have a MCVE for it.

Comment: +1 becomes lock inc, and +n becomes lock xadd. I don't think it's about optimization. -O0 should never *intentionally* produce slower code. (I was using -O3 -march=native -flto)

Comment: @Nybble: Like I said in my answer, I can't reproduce `fetch_add` compiling to `lock xadd` on clang9 or trunk on Godbolt, except when the result is used so it has no choice.  What clang version are you using exactly?

Comment: @Nybble: re: `-O0` should never intentionally produce slower code: well that's exactly true, it intentionally compiles quickly, spending little CPU time optimizing the resulting asm.  My `fetch_add` with `-O0` example is showing we get a `lock xadd` because optimization doesn't notice the result is unused, and/or doesn't try to peephole optimize it down to `lock inc` or `lock add`.  Missing peephole optimizations is exactly the kind of thing we should expect from `-O0`. (Along with massive slowdowns from not doing register allocations, instead reload+spill around every statement for debugging)

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to the source code and results obtained from my machines. I have not acquired an account on llvm bug reports so that will take some time.

Comment: @Nybble: oh, your `lock xadd` finally makes sense now.  Would have saved a lot of time if you'd provided a MCVE.  You *are* using the result, but when adding only 1 the compiler can use the flag result of `inc` or `add`.  https://godbolt.org/z/uVEiTv.  Getting `xadd` when you use `+2` or +3` happens on clang 8 as well, that part is a total red herring.  (It does rule it out as a useful workaround).  Anyway, very likely your performance regression is unrelated to lock inc vs. lock add, unless something is sensitive to code alignment (affected by code size).  e.g. branch prediction aliasing.