# Incrementing one to a variable in IA32 Linux Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to increment 1 to a variable in IA32 Assembly in Linux

```
section .data
num:    dd  0x1

section .text
global _start

_start:

   add    dword [num], 1

   mov    edx, 1
   mov    ecx, [num]
   mov    ebx,1
   mov    eax,4
   int    0x80

   mov    eax,1
   int    0x80
```

Not sure if it's possible to do.

In another literature I saw the follow code:

```
mov eax, num
inc eax
mov num, eax
```

Is it possible to increment a value to a var without moving to a register?

If so, do I have any advantage moving the value to a register?

Comment: Your actual bug is that the `write` system call wants a pointer to its data in `ecx`, not the data itself.  So that should be `mov ecx, num`.  And a dword is 4 bytes, not 1, and this will write it out as raw binary, not human-readable decimal or hex; you could pipe the output into `hexdump` if you want to see it.  Otherwise you get to write a binary-to-decimal conversion routine, which will about triple the length of your program.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks @NateEldredge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to increment a value to a var without moving to a register?

Certainly: `inc dword [num]`.

Like practically all x86 instructions, inc can take either a register or memory operand.  See the instruction description at http://felixcloutier.com/x86/inc; the form `inc r/m32` indicates that you can give an operand which is either a 32-bit **r**egister or 32-bit **m**emory operand (effective address).

If you're interested in micro-optimizations,  it turns out that `add dword [num], 1` may still be somewhat faster, though one byte larger, on certain CPUs.  The specifics are pretty complicated and you can find a very extensive discussion at [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36510865/634919).  This is partly related to the slight difference in effect between the two, which is that `add` will set or clear the carry flag according to whether a carry occurs, while `inc` always leaves the carry flag unchanged.

> If so, do I have any advantage moving the value to a register?

No.  That would make your code larger and probably slower.

Comment: Great! Thank you again, @NateEldredge

Comment: @BrunoCriado: The usual reason for load / inc / store is if you also want the value again later, you still have it in a register.  i.e. to avoid `mov    ecx, [num]`, you'd do the increment in ECX. 
 (Except that's not how to use `write(int fd, void *, size_t)`, but if it had been a printf call or something then you would want the value, not just its address.)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Thanks @PeterCordes